# Issues with signed applet

Tags: java, javascript, jnlp, next-generation-plugin, signed-applet

I am developing an Application that will perform Encryption/Decryption at client side only. I am using Spring, jdk 1.6+, and eclipse. I have developed an Applet that contain cryptographic code it looks like :

```
public void accessToken(){
        try{
            File tmpConfigFile = File.createTempFile("pkcs11", "conf");
            tmpConfigFile.deleteOnExit();
            PrintWriter configWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(tmpConfigFile), true);
            configWriter.println("name=eToken");
            configWriter.println("library=" + "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\eTPKCS11.dll");
            configWriter.println("slotListIndex=0");
            configWriter.println("showInfo=true");

            this.pkcs11Provider = new SunPKCS11(tmpConfigFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Security.addProvider(this.pkcs11Provider);

            CallbackHandler cbh = new DialogCallbackHandler();
            KeyStore.Builder ksBuilder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", null, new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(cbh));                     
            KeyStore ks = ksBuilder.getKeyStore();
            ks.load(null, null);            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have created jar file and signed it, it works well when I run it as "run on Java Applet" on local machine from eclipse also it works well and prompts for password on page load when I open html page which includes this applet but when I click on checkbox that calls this accessToken() applet method it gives error on java console like:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at message.MessageApplet.accessToken(MessageApplet.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and my html page looks like:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            function selectedCity() 
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById('cityRb');

                if(elem.checked)
                {
                    document.messageApplet.accessToken();
                }      
            }
        </SCRIPT></HEAD>
    <BODY >
        <b>This is the Applet</b>
     <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        <!-- applet id can be used to get a reference to the applet object -->
        var attributes = { id:'messageApplet', code:'message.MessageApplet',  width:1, height:1} ;
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'message-applet.jnlp'} ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
    </script>

    <FORM NAME="CityChoice">
        <input type="radio" id="cityRb" name="City" value="Boston" onClick="selectedCity()"> Boston<br>
    </form>
</BODY >
```

and my JNLP file looks like:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Message Applet</title>
        <vendor>Fountainhead</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
<update check="background"/>
    <security>
    <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.6+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="message.jar" main="true" />

    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="Message Applet"
         main-class="message.MessageApplet"
         width="300"
         height="300">
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

all files and jar are in same directory and my applet class is in message folder
please help me I am stuck here...

Comment: *"when I click on checkbox that calls.."* By 'checkbox' DYM the `cityRb` radio? 1) The W3C [definition of a checkbox](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/checkbox) is more along the lines of `<input type="checkbox" name="ny">New York`  2) If that is the case, the JS call is causing the immediate problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006674/how-can-i-get-a-signed-java-applet-to-perform-privileged-operations-when-called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened because you are calling your applet's method from your javascript. Actually when you call any signed applet's method from javascript it behaves as unsigned, because both having own security sand box and you have to perform in that specific sandbox. Now I have made changes in your code as below.

```
final File myFile = (File) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run(){
                    String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") +
                      System.getProperty("file.separator") +
                      "pkcs11.conf";                    
                    return new File(fileName);
                }});
```

this AccessController allow you to create a file on client machine. I am not good in English hence if there any mistakes then sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you call  from (unsigned) javascript a function INSIDE a signed applet, you'll INSTANTLY BREAK the signature. This means that the applet INSTANTLY loses all the priviliges and won't be able to write anything on disk...

Have a look at this, bottom of the page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

> Note:  JavaScript code is treated like unsigned code. When a signed
>   applet is accessed from JavaScript code in an HTML page, the applet is
>   executed within the security sandbox. This implies that the signed
>   applet essentially behaves likes an unsigned applet.**

So you probably have to launch your function right after the init() and then, thorugh liveconnect, call back the js functions on your page FROM the applet notifying the "operation complete"...

Answer (score 0):

You need the policy file too, to allow signed applet to create temp file. 
Please add line number to you code so people can relate stack trace.

I think you code    `File.createTempFile("pkcs11", "conf");` is throwing `SecurityException`.
See this `message.MessageApplet.accessToken(MessageApplet.java:49)` taken from your stack trace.

Comment: thanks for replay, yes you are right that line throws SecurityException. now I have jnlp file in which I have mentioned
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
but still i am facing error. should i place it in my signed jar file if yes the how to refer it in my JNLP file?

Answer (score 0):

You can always give the data to the applet via Javascript for storing them in a FIFO (first in first out) object, and the use a timer on the applet to check the FIFO and process the requests. But I guess returning failure/success code values won't be easy...